# I want to pass data from one screen to another screen in flutter and save the data to ListView/ListTiles

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to pass data from one screen to another screen  in flutter and save the data to ListView/ListTiles. I am not getting
expected result. In the code, on clicking Save button Icon nothing happens ...I am able to pass data to the required screen but on clicking Save Icon it has to save in ListView builder on Main Page and on clicking the ListTile on Main page this screen has to open..I am using path provider but not able to achieve output..I will be thankful if someone could help. Please go through below three classes and I appreaciate if you could tell whats wrong in the code.
Objective:
I am able to get text/data in Content field using data.addContent(_textEditingController.text). But in the OnPressed Save Icon button I tried to Print(content)..nothing is getting displayed in the console..If content is present On clicking Save Icon Button it saves and should to Main screen

```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {

String title = '';
String content = '';
Map<String, List<String>> notes = {
  'titles': [],
  'contents': [],
  'timeSnapShots': [],
};

// void addTitle(String value) => title = value;

void addContent(String value) {
   content = value;
   print('here the messages');
   print(content);
  notifyListeners();
}

/// Create a new note by the given title and content.
void addNote() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  String hours = now.hour < 10 ? '0${now.hour}' : '${now.hour}';
  String minutes = now.minute < 10 ? '0${now.minute}' : '${now.minute}';

  String currentTime = '$hours:$minutes';

  // notes['titles'].add(title);
  notes['contents'].add(content);
  notes['timeSnapShots'].add(currentTime);
  title = '';
  content=content;
  notifyListeners();
  writeFile();
}
void removeNote(int index) {
  // notes['titles'].remove(notes['titles'][index]);
  notes['contents'].remove(notes['contents'][index]);
  notes['timeSnapShots'].remove(notes['timeSnapShots'][index]);
  notifyListeners();
  writeFile();
}

Future<String> appPath() async {
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return document.path;
}


Future<File> appFile() async {
  final path = await appPath();
  return File('$path/data.txt');
 
}
Future writeFile() async {
  final file = await appFile();

  /// The vertical bar help us split data when reading the file
  Future saveData = file.writeAsString(
      '${notes['titles']}|${notes['contents']}|${notes['timeSnapShots']}');

  return saveData;
}

Future readFile() async {
  final file = await appFile();

  List data = (await file.readAsString()).split('|');

  /// I called the (replaceAll) here because when we save list as
  /// string the '[' and ']' of lists also saved with it.
  notes['titles'] =
      data[0].replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').split(',');
  notes['contents'] =
      data[1].replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').split(',');
  notes['timeSnapShots'] =
      data[2].replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '').split(',');

  notifyListeners();
}
}

class AddingTextField extends StatefulWidget {
final int maxLines;
final String hintText;
final String text;
AddingTextField({this.maxLines,this.hintText, this.text});

@override
_AddingTextFieldState createState() => _AddingTextFieldState();
}

class _AddingTextFieldState extends State<AddingTextField> {

TextEditingController _textEditingController;
@override
void initState() {
  _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  _textEditingController.text = widget.text;
  super.initState();
 
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var data = context.watch<Data>();

  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _textEditingController,
      maxLines: widget.maxLines,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: widget.hintText),
      onFieldSubmitted: (input) {
        if(input != null) {
          if(widget.hintText == 'Title'){
            // data.addTitle(input);
            print(input);
          }
          else
            // data.addContent(input);
            data.addContent(_textEditingController.text);
            // data.addContent(input);
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
}


class AddNoteScreen extends StatelessWidget {

final String text;
AddNoteScreen({this.text});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var data = context.watch<Data>();

  

  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomAppBar(
            title: 'Add Note',
            icon: Icons.save,
            onPressed: () {

              
              // data.addNote();
                // Navigator.push(context);
              // print(data.title);
              print(data.content);
              // if (data.title != '' && data.content != '') 
              if (data.content != ''&& data.content != null) 
              {
                data.addNote();
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
          ),
          // AddingTextField(maxLines: 1, hintText: 'Title'),
          Flexible(child: AddingTextField(maxLines: 500, text: text)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for called serialization

Follow up [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

Comment: Please read about [answer]. While the contents of this link might actually solve the problem, link-only answers are discouraged on this site. Links tend to break and then the answer loses its value. It is better to include the essential parts of the link as text in the answer itself and provide the link as a reference. Your plain-text answer looks like: `What you are looking for called serialization Follow up here` which doesn't provide much information except the keyword `serialization`. If you think the link alone can help, post it as a comment (if you have 50 rep) instead.